# Difference between links in revisions and in current body of questions

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, information-display, html-entities

I found an odd bug. Apparently sometimes there are differences between the body in the post in the revision, and in the actual post, regarding presenting hyperlink in the body.

Examples:

1. look at this post:
   *[Android path pattern in deep linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992307/android-path-pattern-in-deep-linking)*
   and its related revision:
   *https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53992307/revisions*

   You can see that there are several hyperlinks that are presented in the revision as hyperlink, but in the actual post are shown as regular text
2. you can see an opposite example on this post: *[Can't make a POST request to Github API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992321/cant-make-a-post-request-to-github-api)* and its related revision: *https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53992321/revisions*.
   In this example, you can see that there is a hyperlink that is presented in the actual post, but in the relevant revision it is shown as regular text (the GitHub link).

How come these differences appear? And is there a way to know according to a revision, if a link will be presented as a link in the actual post or regular text?

Comment: In your first example, I think you need to have it start with `https://`.

Comment: as you can see in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039166/what-is-the-actual-role-of-zookeeper-in-kafka-2-1  the quora link is displayed like a hyperlink, even though it does not contain https://  so that is not the reason @Ollie

Comment: The Quora link is displayed that way because the hyperlink is in both [1] and in [].  Click "Edit post" and look.

Comment: what about my second example? why do you see this difference? @Ollie